# Octopress: Liquid Exception: invalid byte sequence in GB2312, when rake generate

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages, octopress

I had a problem when I tried to generate the post with octopress.

When I type `rake generate`

I have:

```
## Generating Site with Jekyll
identical source/stylesheets/screen.css
Configuration file: e:/github/Jaskey.github.io/_config.yml
            Source: source
       Destination: public
      Generating...
 [31m  Liquid Exception: invalid byte sequence in GB2312 i
0m
jekyll 2.5.3 | Error:  invalid byte sequence in GB2312
```

[image]

Tried set `encoding: utf-8` at _config.yml but not work.

Comment: Can you provide a repository url ? Can be useful to try to spot your problem.

Comment: @DavidJacquel https://github.com/Jaskey/Jaskey.github.io , this repo. I had uninstall ruby(1.93) and install a newer version(2.23), now, with now problem. But actually the older version worked fine before